# Differences between Apache Deft, Webbit and Vert.x

Tags: node.js, jvm

I see a lot of potential of doing Node.JS-like development on the JVM, with its heavily optimized runtime.

At this moment in time, I see three projects that aim to bring a node.js-like style of development to the JVM:

- [Apache Deft](http://incubator.apache.org/deft/)
- [Webbit](http://webbitserver.org/)
- [Vert.x](https://github.com/purplefox/vert.x) (formerly Node.x)

Should these projects team up?
What are their relative strengths and weaknesses?
Which project has the most momentum?

Comment: Why the "not constructive" votes? This is a genuine greenfield for the JVM-space and these seem to be the three projects that are in early stages now. It seems ok to me to find out their differences. Not intended to be flame-bait at all, and not taken as such by the people involved in the project as you can see below. I'll remove the 'vs' part from the title

Comment: +1 Loving the fact that the only answers are from the actual guys who made the three projects in question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the Webbit guy

There is definitely a lot of overlap between the 3 projects. When I built Webbit I was not aware of the other two - had I been, it may well not exist, or I may have spent my time contributing to the others.

I can talk a bit about Webbit...

It is not a multi-purpose evented IO framework. Or network protocol toolkit. Or filesystem abstraction. Webbit only does a small fraction of what the others do.

Webbit is also not a full-featured web-framework. Like Node.JS or the Servlet API, it provides the core building blocks for building higher level frameworks, but leaves this to external projects (like [Webbit-EasyRemote](https://github.com/joewalnes/webbit-easyremote) or [Webbit-REST](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/webbit-rest)).

What Webbit focuses on is being a simple, embeddable, non-blocking, HTTP and WebSocket server.

Because it takes the 'do one thing and do it well' approach, it has also been designed to be used in conjunction with other libraries. It allows external java.util.concurrent.Executors to be passed in and avoids singleton thread contexts, making it particularly well suited for integrating with Actor style concurrency libraries such as [Jetlang](http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/) and [HeySync](https://github.com/osi/heysync).

Vert.x and Deft bring complete frameworks for out-of-the-box Node style development. Webbit is just a small tool that can help HTTP/WebSocket enabled your application. There is a need for both of these and it really depends on your needs (and personal style) as to which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 31):

Disclosure - I'm the vert.x guy :)

Vert.x is a fully fledged platform for building polyglot, scalable, asynchronous web-enabled applications.

It is heavily inspired from node.js but goes further than node.js and provides a distributed event bus which reaches from the server right into client side JavaScript thus creating a super simple model for so-called "real-time' web applications. We also ship with a mailer and a mongodb persistor. There's a full tutorial here http://vertx.io/tutorials.html

But the probably the main thing that sets it apart from other async frameworks is it's polyglot nature. The same (or similar) API is available in Java, Ruby, JavaScript and Groovy (with Clojure, Python and Scala support to follow).

Vert.x really takes advantage of true multi-threading on the JVM to provide scalability and performance than node.js cannot touch.

If you don't want the whole platform. Vert.x can also be used as a library for providing HTTP, TCP, websockets, sockjs, eventbus, etc support in your Java or Groovy application.

For more info pls see the website http://vertx.io

Answer (score 21):

Disclaimer: I'm an Apache Deft committer.

Apache Deft has more in common with tornado and twisted than to node.js, whereas vert.x is heavily influenced by node.js. Tim Fox from wmware is doing a great job with vert.x and the development speed is really impressive.

vert.x has a couple of [examples](https://github.com/vert-x/vert.x/tree/master/vertx-examples/src/main) available.
Some Apache Deft [examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/deft/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/deft/example/).
Apache Deft also has a bigger "[demo application](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/deft/trunk/demo/elastica/)" that should give you an idea of how you could use the framework for other things than http.

AFAIK webbit is currently aiming to be a "WebSocket and HTTP server".

If they should team up? Absolutely :)